# Proper use of ListItem in Microdata?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I am passing the SDTT, and the information even looks orderly in the SDTT result. But I suspect this is going to fail when I go online because I can't find this approach anywhere else.

Do I need to include `itemprop="itemListElement"` in each `div`, and repeat for each item, or have I developed a shortcut that will actually work?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <p itemprop="name">My list</p>
    <p itemprop="description">blurb about the list</p>

   <meta itemprop="position" content="1"/>
        <p itemprop="name">first item name</p>
        <p itemprop="description">blurb about the first item</p>

    <meta itemprop="position" content="2">
    <!-- repeat as above... -->

</div>
```

Please give some guidance regarding the correctness of this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide the `itemListElement` property (with item values).

In your snippet, you are adding all properties to a single `ListItem` (I assume you meant to use `ItemList`, but it doesn’t change the problem). This means that this item has multiple names (`name`), multiple descriptions (`description`), and multiple positions (`position`).

Microdata doesn’t capture the order of the HTML elements. So the following HTML snippets produce equivalent Microdata:

```html
<div itemscope>
  <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
  <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
</div>
```

```html
<div itemscope>
  <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
  <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
</div>
```

(Schema.org defined the `position` property exactly because Microdata doesn’t care about the order in the HTML, so the order has to be specified explicitly if it’s relevant.)